# Is remapping table column names supported in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

JOOQ documentation explains a way to map JOOQ tables to different schema and table names. What about column names? In other words, can I run my JOOQ backed code on a similar structured set of tables where column names are different from the one hard coded, but have the same meaning. For example

PEOPLE(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) -> EMPLOYEES(FName, LName)

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

As of jOOQ 3.9, this is not yet supported out of the box. Here's the relevant feature request https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2949

A workaround would be to implement a [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html), which would take care of such translation on a lower AST transformation level.